# textblob.sentiments gives only positive sentiment

Tags: python, twitter, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I started using textblob (0.11) for my sentiment analysis program with python (2.7).
I am fetching tweets from twitter and decoding the json to extract text from tweets, this text is then fed to sentiment analysis code.
The code works fine but it always outputs sentiment as "pos", everytime. For many texts which are clearly negative, the program shows sentiment as "Pos"

```
import tweepy
import json
import csv
import textblob
import unicodedata
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from textblob.sentiments import NaiveBayesAnalyzer
import sys
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

class listener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self,data):
    decoded = json.loads(data)
   decoded=decoded['text']
    print decoded

   blob = textblob.TextBlob(decoded, analyzer=NaiveBayesAnalyzer())
    print (blob.sentiment)


def on_error(self,status):
    print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

def on_error(self,status):
    print status


twitterStream = Stream(auth,listener())

twitterStream.filter(track=["#Trend"])
```

Kindly help